# How to plot different parts of same Pandas Series column with different colors, having a customized index?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

This is a follow-up for [my previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478506/how-to-plot-different-parts-of-same-pandas-series-column-with-different-colors).

Let's say I have a Series like this:

```
testdf = pd.Series([3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 10], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
```

When plotting, this is the result:

```
testdf.plot()
```

[image: Plot_1]

However, I want to plot, say, the line up to the first 4 values in blue (default) and the rest of the line in red. Trying a solution the way was suggested on the mentioned post above, this is the result I get:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
testdf.plot(ax=ax,color='b')
testdf.iloc[3:].plot(ax=ax,color='r')
```

[image: Plot_2]

I only get the expected result if I don't define my Series with a custom index:

```
testdf = pd.Series([3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 10])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
testdf.plot(ax=ax,color='b')
testdf.iloc[3:].plot(ax=ax,color='r')
```

[image]

How could I achieve the desired result, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to write a comment but it was too long so I write here.

What you want to achieve works well in case you want to plot bars (which are discrete)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.Series([3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 10], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
df.plot(kind = 'bar',color=np.where(df.index<'e','b','r'))
```

But not in case of lines (which are continuous) as you already noticed.

In case you don't want to set custom indices you can use:

```
 df = pd.Series([3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 10])
 cut = 4
 ax = df[:cut].plot(color='b')
 df[(cut-1):].plot(ax=ax, color='r')
```

While using custom indices you should split your series in two parts. One example is doing

```
df = pd.Series([3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 10], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
df1 = pd.Series(np.where(df.index<'e',df.values,np.nan), index=df.index)
df2 = pd.Series(np.where(df.index>='d',df.values,np.nan), index=df.index)
ax = df1.plot(color = 'b')
df2.plot(ax=ax,color='r')
```